# Two different queries in one function in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Basically, I have 2 tables which are RequestOrder and OrderItem. There are 3 variables which are Category, Location and OrderType from RequestOrder and 1 variable from OrderItem table. How do I put another query and result to select all from OrderItem table for `$CCPArray=array('-Select-','Yes','No');` inside this function? Thanks in advance.

```
  function OrderDetails($Role,$UserID,$Xexv){
        $_SESSION['views']=true;

        $RequestID = strtoupper(trim($_REQUEST['RequestID']));

        global $DbHost;
        global $DbUser;
        global $DbPass;
        global $DbName;

        // Database connection

        $link = mysql_connect($DbHost, $DbUser, $DbPass) or die('Could not connect: ' .  mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db($DbName) or die('Could not select database');

        $query="select * from requestorder where RequestID='$RequestID'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

        $CategoryArray=array('Jig','Contactor');
        $LocationArray=array('MUAR','AMK','TPY','STS','GOBM');
        $OrderTypeArray=array('New/Prototype','Duplicate');

        $CCPArray=array('-Select-','Yes','No');


        if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) {
          displayMsg("NoData","");
          exit;
        }


            $query="select RequestID,Category,TypeofOrder,Package,Device,Quantity,Location,CC,Requester,Date,Description,Status,LastUpdate,EmailList from requestorder where RequestID='$RequestID'";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $RequestID=$row[0];
            $RequestID="000"."$RequestID";
            $Category=$row[1];
            $TypeofOrder=$row[2];
            $Package=$row[3];
            $Device=$row[4];
            $Quantity=$row[5];
            $Location=$row[6];

            $CC=$row[7];
            $Requester=$row[8];
            $Date=$row[9];
            $Description=$row[10];
            $Status=$row[11];
            $LastUpdate=$row[12];
            $EmailList=$row[13];

            echo <<<EOT
<center><b>Order Details</b></center>

    <center>

    <form id="container" name="search" onsubmit="return isReadyIn(this);" action="hos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table class="tool">


        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 ><b>Request Infomation</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Request Date : </td><td>$Date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Last Update : </td><td>$LastUpdate</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Request ID : </td><td>$RequestID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Request Status : </td><td>$Status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Requester : </td><td>$Requester</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Category : </td>
            <td><select class="entry" name="Category">
EOT;
foreach ($CategoryArray as $key => $value)

{

if($value==$Category){

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.' selected> '.$value.'';

}

else{

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.'> '.$value.'';

}

}
            echo <<<EOT

                    </select>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="title">Type of Order : </td>
            <td><select class="entry" name="TypeofOrder">
EOT;

foreach ($OrderTypeArray as $key => $value)

{

if($value==$TypeofOrder){

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.' selected> '.$value.'';

}

else{

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.'> '.$value.'';

}

}
    echo <<<EOT

                    </select>
            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr>

                <td class="title">Package : </td><td><input type="text" name="Package" id="Package" value=$Package></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td class="title">Device : </td><td><input type="text" name="Device" id="Device" maxlength="6" value=$Device></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td class="title">Quantity : </td><td><input type="text" name="Quantity" id="Quantity" value=$Quantity></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>

                <td class="title">Location : </td><td><select class="entry" name="Location">
EOT;
foreach ($LocationArray as $key => $value)

{

if($value==$Location){

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.' selected> '.$value.'';

}

else{

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.'> '.$value.'';

}

}
echo <<<EOT

                    </select></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td class="title">Cost Center : </td><td><input type="text" name="CC" id="CC" value=$CC></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td class="title">Email Group : </td><td><input type="text" name="EmailList" id="EmailList" value=$EmailList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td class="title"></td><td><b><p style="font-size:10px;">separate email address by semicolon symbol</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td class="title">Description : </td><td><textarea class="entry" name="Description" id="Description">$Description</textarea></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="repeatingSection1">
EOT;


        $query="select ItemID,OrderID,Supplier,WBS,PUC,Total,PR,CCP,PR_Date,PO,PO_Date,ExpectedDelivery,Shipment_Date,Remarks,AssetNumber,Quotation_Date,name_of_uploaded_Quotation,name_of_uploaded_PR,name_of_uploaded_PO from orderitem where RequestID='$RequestID'";
        $result=mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());


        $ItemCount=mysql_num_rows($result);
        $ItemCounter=1;

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
      {
        if($ItemCounter==1){$Label="Main Item";}
        else{

            $divID="repeatingSection". $ItemCounter;

        echo <<<EOT
        <div id="$divID">
EOT;
        $Label="Sub Item" . $ItemCounter;
     }

        $Supplier =$row['Supplier'];
        $WBS =$row['WBS'];
        $PUC =$row['PUC']; 
        $Total =$row['Total']; 
        $PR =$row['PR']; 
        $CCP =$row['CCP']; 
        $PR_Date =$row['PR_Date']; 
        $PO =$row['PO']; 
        $PO_Date =$row['PO_Date']; 
        $ExpectedDelivery =$row['ExpectedDelivery']; 
        $Shipment_Date= $row['Shipment_Date']; 
        $Remarks =$row['Remarks']; 
        $AssetNumber =$row['AssetNumber']; 
        $Quotation_Date= $row['Quotation_Date']; 
        $ItemID=$row['ItemID'];
        $name_of_uploaded_Quotation=$row['name_of_uploaded_Quotation'];
        $name_of_uploaded_PR=$row['name_of_uploaded_PR'];
        $name_of_uploaded_PO=$row['name_of_uploaded_PO'];


    echo <<<EOT


        <table class="tool2" id="tool2">
        <td><input type="button" value="X" class="delItem" id="delItem$ItemID$ItemCounter" onclick="delForm(this);"></td><td><p><span id="displayCount">$Label</span></p></td>


        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 ><b>Quotation Infomation</b></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="title">Supplier : </td><td><input type="text" name="Supplier$ItemCounter" id="Supplier" value=$Supplier></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Quotation upload : </td><td>
EOT;

if($name_of_uploaded_Quotation==''){

    echo <<<EOT

            <input type="file" name="QuotationUpload$ItemCounter" id="QuotationUpload">

EOT;
}
else {

    echo <<<EOT

     <p id="linkQu$ItemCounter"><a id="urllinkQu$ItemCounter" href="downloads/$name_of_uploaded_Quotation" target="_blank">$name_of_uploaded_Quotation</a>
      <span><input type="button" value="X" class="delItem" id="delqu$ItemID$ItemCounter" onclick="delUpload(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="QuotationUpload$ItemCounter" id="QuotationUpload$ItemCounter" value=$name_of_uploaded_Quotation></p>   
EOT;
}
        echo <<<EOT

        </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="Quotation_Date$ItemCounter" id="Quotation_Date" value=$Quotation_Date>




        <tr>
                <td class="title">Order ID : </td><td><input type="text" name="OrderID$ItemCounter" id="OrderID"></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
                <td class="title">Per Unit Cost : </td><td><input type="text" name="PUC$ItemCounter" id="PUC" value=$PUC></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td class="title">Total Cost : </td><td><input type="text" name="Total$ItemCounter" id="Total" value=$Total></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 ><b>Finance Information</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <td class="title">WBS : </td><td><input type="text" name="WBS$ItemCounter" id="WBS" value=$WBS></td>


        </tr>
                <tr>

                <td class="title">Asset Number : </td><td><input type="text" name="AssetNumber$ItemCounter" id="AssetNumber" value=$AssetNumber></td>


        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 ><b>Delivery Information</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <td class="title">PR : </td><td><input type="text" name="PR$ItemCounter" id="PR" value=$PR></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td class="title">PR upload : </td><td>
EOT;

if($name_of_uploaded_PR==''){

    echo <<<EOT

            <input type="file" name="PRUpload$ItemCounter" id="PRUpload">

EOT;
}
else {

    echo <<<EOT

      <p id="linkPR$ItemCounter"><a id="urllinkPR$ItemCounter" href="downloads/$name_of_uploaded_PR" target="_blank">$name_of_uploaded_PR</a>
      <input type="button" value="X" class="delItem" id="delpr$ItemID$ItemCounter" onclick="delUpload(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="PRUpload$ItemCounter" id="PRUpload$ItemCounter" value=$name_of_uploaded_PR></p>
EOT;
}
        echo <<<EOT

        </td>
        </tr>       
                <input type="hidden" name="PR_Date$ItemCounter" id="PR_Date" value=$PR_Date>



        <tr>

                <td class="title">CCP Approval : </td><td><select class="entry" name="CCP$ItemCounter" id="CCP">
EOT;
foreach ($CCPArray as $key => $value)

{

if($value==$CCP){

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.' selected> '.$value.'';

}

else{

echo '<OPTION value='.$value.'> '.$value.'';

}

}
echo <<<EOT


                    </select></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td class="title">PO : </td><td><input type="text" name="PO$ItemCounter" id="PO" value=$PO></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">PO upload : </td><td>
EOT;

if($name_of_uploaded_PO==''){

    echo <<<EOT

            <input type="file" name="POUpload$ItemCounter" id="POUpload">

EOT;
}
else {

    echo <<<EOT

     <p id="linkPO$ItemCounter"><a id="urllinkPO$ItemCounter" href="downloads/$name_of_uploaded_PO" target="_blank">$name_of_uploaded_PO</a>
      <input type="button" value="X" class="delItem" id="delpo$ItemID$ItemCounter" onclick="delUpload(this);">
      <input type="hidden" name="POUpload$ItemCounter" id="POUpload$ItemCounter" value=$name_of_uploaded_PO></p>
EOT;
}
        echo <<<EOT

        </td>
        </tr>       
                <input type="hidden" name="PO_Date$ItemCounter" id="PO_Date" value=$PO_Date>


        <tr>
                <td class="title">Expected Delivery : </td><td><input type="text" name="ExpectedDelivery$ItemCounter" id="ExpectedDelivery" value=$ExpectedDelivery></td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="Shipment_Date$ItemCounter" id="Shipment_Date" value=$Shipment_Date>


        <tr>
            <td class="title">Remarks : </td><td><textarea class="entry" name="Remarks$ItemCounter" id="Remarks">$Remarks</textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="ItemID$ItemCounter" id="ItemID" value=$ItemID>
        <br></table></div>


EOT;

    $ItemCounter++;
      } 




    echo <<<EOT
        <table>
            <input type="hidden" name="lastSectionCount" value=$ItemCount id="lastSectionCount">
        <input type="hidden" name="OriginalItemCount" value=$ItemCount id="OriginalItemCount">
        <input type="hidden" name="ItemCount" value=$ItemCount id="ItemCount">
        <input type="hidden" name="Status" value=$Status>
        <input type="hidden" name="Pg" value="UpdateOrder_Store">

        <input type="hidden" name="Role" value=$Role id="Role">
        <input type="hidden" name="RequestID" value=$RequestID id="RequestID">
        <input type="hidden" name="Xexv" value=$Xexv id="Xexv">

        <input type="hidden" name="UserID" value=$UserID id="UserID">
         <p id="hidden"><!-- Insert Hidden input tag here --></p>
        </table>



        <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%"><input type="submit" class="bluebutton" value="Submit"></td>

            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" id="delete" onclick="delete_order();"></td>

            <td><input type="button" value="Add Sub-Item" class="subItem" id="subItem" onclick="addForm();"></td>
        </tr>

        </table>

        </form>

        <div id="clone" style="display: none;"> 

        <table class="tool2" id="tool2">
        <td><input type="button" value="X" class="delItem" id="delItem21" onclick="delForm(this);"></td><td><p><span id="displayCount">Main Item</span></p></td>


        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 ><b>Quotation Infomation</b></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="title">Supplier : </td><td><input type="text" name="Supplier1" id="Supplier" value=></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Quotation upload : </td><td>      
            <input type="file" name="QuotationUpload1" id="QuotationUpload">

        </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="Quotation_Date1" id="Quotation_Date" value=0000-00-00>




        <tr>
                <td class="title">Order ID : </td><td><input type="text" name="OrderID1" id="OrderID"></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
                <td class="title">Per Unit Cost : </td><td><input type="text" name="PUC1" id="PUC" value=></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td class="title">Total Cost : </td><td><input type="text" name="Total1" id="Total" value=></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 ><b>Finance Information</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <td class="title">WBS : </td><td><input type="text" name="WBS1" id="WBS" value=></td>


        </tr>
                <tr>

                <td class="title">Asset Number : </td><td><input type="text" name="AssetNumber1" id="AssetNumber" value=></td>


        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan=2 ><b>Delivery Information</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

                <td class="title">PR : </td><td><input type="text" name="PR1" id="PR" value=></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
            <td class="title">PR upload : </td><td>     
            <input type="file" name="PRUpload1" id="PRUpload">

        </td>
        </tr>       
                <input type="hidden" name="PR_Date1" id="PR_Date" value=0000-00-00>



        <tr>

                <td class="title">CCP Approval : </td><td><select class="entry" name="CCP1" id="CCP"><OPTION value=-Select- selected> -Select-<OPTION value=Yes> Yes<OPTION value=No> No                                

                    </select></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td class="title">PO : </td><td><input type="text" name="PO1" id="PO" value=></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">PO upload : </td><td>     
            <input type="file" name="POUpload1" id="POUpload">

        </td>
        </tr>       
                <input type="hidden" name="PO_Date1" id="PO_Date" value=0000-00-00>


        <tr>
                <td class="title">Expected Delivery : </td><td><input type="text" name="ExpectedDelivery1" id="ExpectedDelivery" value=></td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="Shipment_Date1" id="Shipment_Date" value=0000-00-00>


        <tr>
            <td class="title">Remarks : </td><td><textarea class="entry" name="Remarks1" id="Remarks"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="ItemID1" id="ItemID" value=2>
        <br></table></div>


EOT;
    mysql_close($link);
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the rest of the `OrderDetails` function? It doesn't seem to return.

Comment: the function is too long but I've added the rest of the function

Comment: I think you can just repeat the code that executes the query and let it execute another query. Btw, this seems to be a beginner question. If you're learning PHP and MySQL, do yourself a favor and skip the `mysql_*` functions. These are old functions that have been removed in PHP 7. Use a more modern API like PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks, but for the time being I have to use this function. Is there any way to fix this code?

Comment: Try to split the one big function into more smaller, for example, you can avoid showing html by wrapping it into separate functions.Try to use MVC so semarate Model (data) View (html) and Controller (logic) into separate methods. So you can debug reading from the database and then displaying the HTML properly with the right data